# Angular 5 project is unable to upgrade in to Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, angular7, angular-cli-v7

My current Angular cli Version is 1.6.6 and
Angular Version is 5.2.2

I am trying to update it to Angular 7 and new angular cli version is 7.3.6

When I try to upgrade using `ng update @angular/cli`, an error in console prints

```
The specified command update is invalid. For available options, see ng help.

Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.6) is greater than your local
version (1.6.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

**It seems like this update command has been removed**. I have followed the official [documentation](https://update.angular.io/).

[image: Instrutions]
Any suggestions to upgrade?

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Comment: in which case, you should be on 1.7.x cli? possibly even 1.8.x now

Comment: Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.6) is greater than your local
version (1.6.6). The local Angular CLI version is used. This is the message to be exact

Comment: Update the local version in your `package.json` too: `npm install @angular/cli -D`

Comment: looks like they change the numbering again, 7.3.6 is the latest, 1.6.6 is older, so update the version in oyur package.json

Comment: @Igor what is the `--D` for? if its for saving to dev dependencies, its `--save-dev`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - `-D` is an alias for `--save-dev`

Comment: @Igor im pretty sure `--save-dev` is an alias for `--save-devDependencies`

Comment: Well the official update says exactly what needs to be done. https://update.angular.io/ But If you follow that, this error comes

Comment: @mast3rd3mon [documentation of npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), "-D, --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.". Admittedly I did have one to many `-` characters.

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon did you run all 3 commands it says in order? `npm install -g @angular/cli`, `npm install @angular/cli` and `ng update @angular/cli`?

Comment: I ran them in order. Exactly as it is mention

Comment: Well. found a related link too. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9408 They had the same issue as of mine

Comment: are you on node v8 or later?

Comment: Node version is v8.9.4

Comment: @Igor you were right. It worked. The issue was, previously it did not update the package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the official documentation.

It says to run `npm install @angular/cli` but actually you need to run

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

This will update the package.json, so that you can continue from there.

After this, you can run `ng update @angular/cli` and so on.